# How to indicate width is 'flexible' in Android layout editor?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to keep distance from left and right, but keep width of the widget flexible. How can I define it in Android?

[image]

Comment: layout_width="wrap_content", this will allow you to "change" width based on elements inside the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand your question, but i guess you're looking for a way to give your `ListView` a width which is dynamic based on e.g. the screen width.

You should have a look at `MATCH_PARENT`

> LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to
>   be laid out. See ViewGroup Layout Attributes for a list of all child
>   view attributes that this class supports.
>
> The base LayoutParams class just describes how big the view wants to
>   be for both width and height. For each dimension, it can specify one
>   of:
>
> - FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), which
>     means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)
> - WRAP_CONTENT, which means that the view wants to be just big enough to
>     enclose its content (plus padding)
> - an exact number
>
> There are subclasses of LayoutParams for different subclasses of ViewGroup. For
>   example, AbsoluteLayout has its own subclass of LayoutParams which
>   adds an X and Y value.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html